# Determine when windows-shell command has finished in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-shell

I'm writing a powershell script to compress a file directory and then send it to a remote location via FTP.
I'm creating the zip file using the shell application.

The problem I've encountered is that the *CopyHere* command returns immediately, and the copy happens on a different thread. Obviously, I cannot begin the FTP transfer until zip file is created.

How do I determine when the zip file creation is complete?

Some sample code:

```
if(test-path($destZipFilePath)) {
    remove-item $destZipFilePath;
}
set-content $destZipFilePath("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18));

$shellApp = new-object -com shell.application;
$zipFile = $shellApp.Namespace($destZipFilePath);
$zipSource = $shellApp.Namespace($fullDeployDirectory);

$zipFile.CopyHere($zipSource);
############################################################
# CopyHere is called asynchronously                        #
# I do not know how to determine if it has completed       #
# hence this horrible hack                                 #
############################################################

Start-Sleep -m 10000;

############################################################

$zipFile = $null
$zipSource = $null
$shellApp = $null

    
#Now we FTP the zipped file to the FTP servers

$ftpDest = "{0}/{1}" -f ($ftpAddress, $zipFileName);
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $password);
$webClient.UploadFile($ftpDest, $$destZipFilePath);
```

---

**Edit (10 years later)**

If you got here because you are trying to compress a folder, Powershell now provides the [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1) commandlet.

Sadly, still no answer to the question of how to wait for a shellApp method to complete.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use some other synchronous solution like [7Zip](http://7-zip.org/) or the [PowerShell Community Extenions](http://pscx.codeplex.com)?  PSCX provides a convenient set of cmdlet wrappers around 7Zip.  Both are free and would be synchronous e.g.:

```
Write-Zip dirToZip dir.zip
```

Comment: The filesystem module from the MSDN PowershellPack is also a good option. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack

Answer (score -1):

late answer but you could try this

```
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.